# Send steam offer with Steam API

Tags: php, steam, steam-web-api

Im searching in Steam API methods to sending Steam offer and cant find. Its possible with API or do you know maybe other method? Im wanna use this in PHP / Symfony.

Answer (score 6):

You can't currently create a trade offer through the API. IEconService currently only supports Get, Decline and Cancel. (https://developer.valvesoftware.com/wiki/Steam_Web_API/IEconService)

You could create a bot to do this. See https://www.reddit.com/r/SteamBot/comments/2ucxbr/how_to_send_a_trade_offer/ for more information.

Answer (score 2):

Open the developer console in your browser and check for the http request made when an trade offer is sent then you can make the same thing in a php script.